# Ignored and watched tags seem broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, ignored-tags, tag-watching

For the longest time my ignored tags have been working but today they are not.

They work on the home page but not the /questions page. However, if you choose the "Gray out questions" option then that fails.

Arqade is the only site I've ever had a long-standing ignore list so I don't think I can blame cache.

The same behavior seems to be exhibited on Stack Overflow but I added those ignore tags just moment ago so cache could be an issue.

If it matters, I am using Chrome x64 v91.0.4472.77 on Windows 10

Via comments, this issue has been confirmed for Watched Tags as well.

[image]

Comment: This is happening on [scifi.se] as well.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing now on [SO's main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), questions with my watched tags aren't highlighted, and with ignored tags aren't greying out either.

Comment: @zcoop98 Yeah, I don't see highlighted posts _anywhere_. Not on the home page, not on `/questions`, and not on Custom Filters pages.

Comment: We are experiencing this at [rpg.se](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11583/watched-and-ignored-is-not-displaying-for-me) as well.

Comment: We've identified a probable cause of this issue but we likely won't be able to dig into it until tomorrow - thanks for raising it! And apologies for the inconvenience - I know having to look at tags you're not interested in can be annoying at times. :(

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [Did a change stop .tagged-interesting from working on Firefox?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408293/4642212).

Comment: The cause has been identified, and quite unusually and unexpectedly: **it wasn't even me!** Will be fixed ASAP.

Comment: @Marc if not you, then who? *preparing trout*

Comment: [Same thing on politics](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5842/did-ignored-tags-feature-change)

Comment: [It happens on Physics too](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13621/220004)

Comment: Anyone landing here wondering about [tag:status-completed]: You're looking for a revision > 2021.6.11.39480. You can find the current revision (*rev.*) in the footer of any page.

Comment: @MarcGravell If this is (status-completed), should maybe also the bug reports on per-site metas marked as such. Two of them are linked in the above comments, other ones I was able to find were: [Was there a change in the theme in the main page?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33686) on [math.meta.se], [Watched tags highlighting lost](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5071) on MathOverflow Meta, [Did a change stop .tagged-interesting from working on Firefox?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408293) on Stack Overflow Meta ...

Comment: ... [Watched tags not displaying](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5025) on [chemistry.meta.se], [Watched Tags: no coloring questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8787) on [tex.meta.se], [Watched and ignored is not displaying for me](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11583) on [rpg.meta.se], [Just me or is tag highlighting not functioning?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3757) on [graphicdesign.meta.se].

Comment: There is also a post on [arqade.meta.se], but that one is already marked as (status-completed): [Are questions tagged with one of my Watched Tags no longer highlighted?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15867)

Answer (score 38):

Sorry about that. What happened here: the favorites/ignored feature is implemented client-side; a UI tweak changed the DOM in a way that broke the jQuery selector, meaning that it no longer found the tag data. I've put a PR together that fixes this - we'll get it deployed as soon as we can (after validation, etc).

Comment: Although it risks being perceived as rude and snarky, I have to ask anyway: is the validation of which you speak something new that is being developed, or was it there when the initial "UI tweak" was deployed? If it was there, why did the validation process not catch the regression created by the change to the DOM? Can the validation process be improved? This is not the first time that a UI tweak has broken features on SO. I realize that maintaining a site this large is far from trivial, but that's why validation is so important. I have not previously seen reference to it being done.

Comment: @CodyGray I understand your point, and we're always looking to improve things; our server-side testing story is a lot better than our client-side testing story, which is a large part of why this got through. I *believe* the UI folks have plans here, but ultimately: I'm mostly a server-side person, so I won't opine too strongly here. They don't let me near crayons much.

Comment: That's probably for the best. If you're anything like me, you'd probably end up just trying to eat the crayons. :-) Yeah, most of these regressions we see and complain about are strictly client-side. Even with the little bit that I know about this client-side stuff, I can see how it would be harder to validate. Incidentally, it looks like another regression has just occurred where system fonts are no longer being used  on MSE or MSO. (Styles are actually different from SO.) Could that somehow be related to this fix?

Comment: @CodyGray sounds unlikely to be related

Comment: Those pesky front-enders only want to be Angular or React-ful or Coffeebean Script or whatever the latest trend is. Back in my day, we manipulated the DOM and abused `slideToggle()`, uphill, both ways, and we liked it!

Comment: I see the stats has been marked as completed, but what happened to the question highlighting?

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix.  I'm now seeing watched tags highlighted in my views.  :-)

Comment: Strangely, I was away from my computer today and saw everything was OK on my phone.  Get home and discover my PC with Chrome still has the problem.

Comment: @TobySpeight Really? It's still broken for me in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: @user673679 Might you be using cached stylesheets and/or scripts?

Comment: @MarcGravell Should the highlighting be fixed? If so, it seems broken for a lot of us. Caches cleared and all.

Comment: I see it working now in tag filtered lists but not on main page

Comment: This is still broken on the Home page and severely hampered on any other page, maybe one out of 100 questions get highlighted on non-Home page lists.

Comment: @Casey it all seems fine here; I'll take another look at the homepage in Monday - do you have links to some other pages you're seeing problems?

Comment: non-Home pages (Questions and searching by tag) seem to work. Home is still borked...Just found a perfect example. A question that is at the top of both Home and Questions and `c++` tag, is highlighted in Questions and 'c++` filter search as it should; but, not Home. TIL that tag filters only highlight/dim questions if they contain an additional tag other than the one filtered and it's in your watched/ignored list. Makes sense, otherwise every question would be highlighted or dimmed (if you filter for a tag you ignore).

Comment: FYI: "watched" tag highlighting is still 100% non-operational for me in Chromium (Chrome and Edge). I.e. I load the homepage, which defaults to "Interesting", and I see no posts highlighted, in spite of numerous ones having tags that I've included in the "watched" tags settings. If there is something that users are expected to do following the update to correct the problem, it would be useful to include that information here. If it should "just work" after the fix, then it's not fixed yet.

Comment: And for the record: I have tried deleting all cookies and site data in the browser, and made sure that the browser is set to accept all cookies. I don't even know whether any of this is supposed to relate to the "watched tags highlighting" feature or not, but doing all of that didn't affect the problem. It still occurs.

Comment: @Peter OK, I'm pinging the team who delivered this feature... it genuinely wasn't me this time

Comment: @MarcGravell Stupid question: Source Control + Feature branch + rollback, yes? If no, whhhhyyy was the feature allowed to be pushed to the main branch without testing?

Comment: @Casey respectfully: overlooking a side-effect in an unrelated feature doesn't mean it wasn't tested - it means that we're human and have finite resources; as for reverting: yes, possible, but that's a trade off between many factors, and a *relatively* minor client-side cosmetic failure - as undesirable as it is - can still be the better choice than a revert, partial or total, of a large set of changes which could have other unanticipated consequences. I've contacted the folks involved, and they're going to look again on Monday.

Comment: @MarcGravell, duplicate report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366477/why-is-tag-highlighting-broken

Comment: @Luuklag deploy going out now, btw

Comment: @PeterDuniho hopefully we should be good now!

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell, looks fixed to me!

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell, works again on the homepage!

Comment: So is this fully working yet? I had accepted this answer the other day since my Arqade page was working but I didn't notice the nuances which people brought up since then so I unaccepted. Has the team properly tested everything?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I can't speak to the testing question, but I can confirm that the issue that I'd noticed, i.e. the homepage still not working even while tag-based searches had been fixed, has also now been fixed.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Interesting. On SO watched tag highlighting seems to work on both the homepage and questions page.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: right...that's what I was trying to say (at least, about the homepage...I don't use the Questions page so didn't comment on that). Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: This morning for the first time since this problem surfaced, I have my highlighting working again on the main StackOverflow page.  Yay!  That was a long week.

Comment: Looks like this is broken again.

Comment: @Spencer may want to report it as a new thing; I haven't worked here in a bit

Answer (score 5):

The same happens for me. I have a very long standing ignore list on SO, but as of now questions show up that should be ignored.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I feel silly for not knowing about wildcards, `*minecraft*`, all these years!

Comment: I don't really use Ignored Tags but I always assumed that they only work on the home page and not on `/questions`. No?

Comment: @41686d6564 As far as I can remember it has worked in both locations. Albeit, it does seem to be filtering on the home page as of now. However, if you choose the "Gray out questions" option then that fails.