# Profile images are pushed to next line if tags extend too far to the right

Tags: bug, status-completed, question-lists

This seemed to pop up at the same time as [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken).

Suddenly, asker's profile information is being pushed to the next line if the tags take up too much room:

[image: Example]

I can't remember how this was handled previously, but I've never seen the profile pushed to the next line like that. I think the tags used to just go over-top of the card?

> Edge, Version 91.0.864.41 (Official build) (64-bit)

---

More examples:

[image] [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912695/kubernetes-external-secrets-operator-error-invalidclienttokenid-the-security)

[image] [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912631/devops-cicd-parallel-stages-deployment)

---

Easy way to reproduce this bug:

Search for some long tags. [firebase-realtime-d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database+firebase-authentication) and [azure-pipelines-release-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-pipelines-release-pipeline) are good candidates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whoops! I fixed this on June 15th ~10pm UTC, but my computer blue-screened after finishing this build and I forgot to update this meta post.

I think this broke a few different ways with some refactoring during the launch of Collectives and this was an unintentional side effect. This has been fixed and the user info should no longer appear on the left side of a post.

The source of this problem was some legacy CSS. Efforts to move more of our CSS into more atomic classes through [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) will prevent issues like this from happening in the future.