# Having many long tags on a question breaks question list layout

Tags: bug, design

This only happens on `.../questions` pages, not on site home pages.

Here's a screenshot from Aviation.SE:

[image: pic]

Comment: Happens on MSE too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlAeF.png

Comment: Duplicate: [Profile images are pushed to next line if tags extend too far to the right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366329/profile-images-are-pushed-to-next-line-if-tags-extend-too-far-to-the-right)

Comment: To be clear, the desired outcome is that the post information is still on the right side, even if the tags are too long. Is that correct?

Comment: @VLAZ Yep. Either the asker info should be pushed down (not to the left), or the tag list should be split in two lines.

Comment: I suggest adding this to the question. A bug report that just says "it's wrong" without specifying parameters for "right" is not very useful.

Comment: @VLAZ It's closed as a dupe now, so it probably doesn't matter.