# Why is tag highlighting broken?

Tags: bug, tags, design, tag-watching

I've recently started observing that the highlighting of questions in a site's overview page has stopped working.

I've observed this on:

- [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

  [image: DBA sql-server tagged question not highlighted]
  *sql_server tagged question  not highlighted*
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

  [image: Serverfault sql-server tagged question not highlighted]
  *sql-server tagged question not highlighted*
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

  [image: Superuser windows-10 tagged question not highlighted]
  *windows-10 tagged question not highlighted*

...and possibly others affected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignored and watched tags seem broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken)

Comment: Current revision is 2021.6.11.39480 so I expect the fix is not deployed yet, in case the status-completed of the duplicate confuses you.

Comment: @rene comments on the answer of the dupe state that there is more to be fixed on monday (later today)

Comment: @Luuklag yeah, I was just reading that. It will be The Longest Monday ™

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for pointing that out. I guess part of finding existing Q&As is the "correct" wording. _I did search before I posted_ Thanks.

Comment: No problem @JohnK.N., you don't always find those duplicates because difference in terminology. That is also their value at the same time. Now anyone who will search for highlighting will find your post, and thus the other post as well.

Comment: Try again .... (watches build) ... *now*

Comment: And it works (again).

Comment: Sorry about the inconvenience. We obviously don't like breaking things - this was an unanticipated side-effect that rippled into multiple places. We fixed one on Friday, but it needed a second kick.